# React Native Hooks Search Filter FlatList

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I am trying to make a Covid19 React Native Expo app. It contains a search filter from which user will select a country then the selected country results will be shown to the user. I keep getting this error on my Android device  "Unexpected Identifier You" while on web pack the countries load but they don't filter correctly.

Working Snack Link: https://snack.expo.io/@moeez71/ac5758

Here is my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  ActivityIndicator,
  Alert,
  FlatList,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  TextInput,
} from "react-native";

export default function ABCDEE() {
  const [arrayholder, setArrayholder] = useState([]);
  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  const fetchAPI = () => {
    return fetch("https://api.covid19api.com/countries")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        setData(responseJson);
        setLoading(false);
        setArrayholder(responseJson);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchAPI();
  });

  const searchData = (text) => {
    const newData = arrayholder.filter((item) => {
      const itemData = item.Country.toUpperCase();
      const textData = text.toUpperCase();
      return itemData.indexOf(textData) > -1;
    });

    setData(newData);
    setText(text);
  };

  const itemSeparator = () => {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          height: 0.5,
          width: "100%",
          backgroundColor: "#000",
        }}
      />
    );
  };

  return (
    <View>
      {loading === false ? (
        <View style={styles.MainContainer}>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.textInput}
            onChangeText={(text) => searchData(text)}
            value={text}
            underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
            placeholder="Search Here"
          />

          <FlatList
            data={data}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
            ItemSeparatorComponent={itemSeparator}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <Text style={styles.row}>{item.Country}</Text>
            )}
            style={{ marginTop: 10 }}
          />
        </View>
      ) : (
        <Text>loading</Text>
      )}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  MainContainer: {
    paddingTop: 50,
    justifyContent: "center",
    flex: 1,
    margin: 5,
  },

  row: {
    fontSize: 18,
    padding: 12,
  },

  textInput: {
    textAlign: "center",
    height: 42,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "#009688",
    borderRadius: 8,
    backgroundColor: "#FFFF",
  },
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You had made two mistakes in the above code

1. useEffect second parameter should be a empty array for it act as **componentDidMount()**

   **useEffect(() => {
       fetchAPI();
     },[])**
2. in FlatList renderItem need to destructure the item.

   ```
     renderItem={( {item}  ) => <Text style={styles.row}
      >{item.Country}</Text>}
   ```

Working code

```
    import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react"
import { ActivityIndicator, Alert, FlatList, Text, StyleSheet, View, TextInput } from 'react-native';

export default function ABCDEE(){


  const [arrayholder,setArrayholder] =useState([])
  const[text, setText] = useState('')
  const[data, setData] = useState([])
  const [loading , setLoading] = useState(true)

  const fetchAPI = ()=> {
    return fetch('https://api.covid19api.com/countries')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
        setData(responseJson)
        setLoading(false)
        setArrayholder(responseJson)
    }

    )
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
}

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchAPI();
  },[])


  const searchData= (text)=>  {
    const newData = arrayholder.filter(item => {
      const itemData = item.Country.toUpperCase();
      const textData = text.toUpperCase();
      return itemData.indexOf(textData) > -1
    });

      setData(newData)
      setText(text)
    }

   const itemSeparator = () => {
      return (
        <View
          style={{
            height: .5,
            width: "100%",
            backgroundColor: "#000",
          }}
        />
      );
    }

      return (
          <View style={{flex:1}} >
    {loading === false ?  
        <View style={styles.MainContainer}>

        <TextInput 
         style={styles.textInput}
         onChangeText={(text) => searchData(text)}
         value={text}
         underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
         placeholder="Search Here" />

        <FlatList
          data={data}
          keyExtractor={ (item, index) => index.toString() }
          ItemSeparatorComponent={itemSeparator}
          renderItem={( {item}  ) => <Text style={styles.row}
           >{item.Country}</Text>}
          style={{ marginTop: 10 }} />

      </View>
      : <Text>loading</Text>}

      </View>
    );
  }


const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  MainContainer: {
    paddingTop: 50,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    flex: 1,
    margin: 5,

  },

  row: {
    fontSize: 18,
    padding: 12
  },

  textInput: {

    textAlign: 'center',
    height: 42,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#009688',
    borderRadius: 8,
    backgroundColor: "#FFFF"

  }
});
```

Comment: its working properly in web but on my android device it is not showing the countries

Comment: can u please check using snack?  it will let u see in android and web

Comment: add **style={{flex:1}}** for root view to work in android, i have updated the working code.

Comment: @bk7 could u please show how to add another key filter instead of only `.Country` ?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues with your implementation. I will point out some mistake/ignorance. You can clean up you code accordingly.

1. Do not create 2 state to keep same data. ie. arrayholder and data.
2. Change text value on search, don't the data. based on that text filter
3. Hooks always define some variable to be watched.

Update: Seems there is an issue with flex in android view, i use fixed height it is visible.

Just a hack for android issue. `minHeight`

```
MainContainer: {
    paddingTop: 50,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    flex: 1,
    margin: 5,
    minHeight: 800,
  },
```

Working link: https://snack.expo.io/kTuT3uql_

Updated code:

```
 import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  ActivityIndicator,
  Alert,
  FlatList,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  TextInput,
} from 'react-native';

export default function ABCDEE() {
  const [text, setText] = useState('');
  const [state, setState] = useState({ data: [], loading: false }); // only one data source
  const { data, loading } = state;
  const fetchAPI = () => {
    //setState({data:[], loading: true});
    return fetch('https://api.covid19api.com/countries')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        setState({ data, loading: false }); // set only data
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchAPI();
  }, []); // use `[]` to avoid multiple side effect

  const filterdData = text // based on text, filter data and use filtered data
    ? data.filter(item => {
        const itemData = item.Country.toUpperCase();
        const textData = text.toUpperCase();
        return itemData.indexOf(textData) > -1;
      })
    : data; // on on text, u can return all data
  console.log(data);
  const itemSeparator = () => {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          height: 0.5,
          width: '100%',
          backgroundColor: '#000',
        }}
      />
    );
  };

  return (
    <View>
      {loading === false ? (
        <View style={styles.MainContainer}>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.textInput}
            onChangeText={text => setText(text)}
            value={text}
            underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
            placeholder="Search Here"
          />
          <FlatList
            data={filterdData}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
            ItemSeparatorComponent={itemSeparator}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <Text style={styles.row}>{item.Country}</Text>
            )}
            style={{ marginTop: 10 }}
          />
        </View>
      ) : (
        <Text>loading</Text>
      )}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  MainContainer: {
    paddingTop: 50,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    //flex: 1,
    margin: 5,
    height: 800,
  },

  row: {
    fontSize: 18,
    padding: 12,
  },

  textInput: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    height: 42,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#009688',
    borderRadius: 8,
    backgroundColor: '#333',
  },
});
```

Comment: Flat List is still rendering empty :(

Comment: let me check data

Comment: if u check my snack it works on web but if i try on android device it renders empty

Comment: try console here
```renderItem={({ item }) => {
  console.log(item)
  return (<Text style={styles.row}>{item.Country}</Text>)
}}```

Comment: https://reactnativecode.com/search-bar-filter-on-flatlist-json-data/   i took help from here, code was in class component and i converted this to functional component as all my other components are function based

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214492/discussion-between-xdeepakv-and-moeez-atlas).

Comment: seems there is issue with flex in android view

Comment: any way around it?

Comment: added fixed hight for time being

Comment: Okay I'll take a look in snack

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the error comes from the catch block when you fetch your data. The response comes with a 200 status, so it's not an issue with the endpoint itself. I console.logged the response and it seems fine. The problem is when you parse the response and try to use it in the second then() block, so the catch block fires up. I could not debug it right in the editor you use, but I would check what type of object I'm receiving from the API call.

Comment: its a json object

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your question but I didn't want this to get lost in the comments as it is directly related with your efforts on this app.

App Store and Google Play Store no longer accept apps that have references to Covid-19 https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=03142020a

You can only publish apps about Covid-19 if you are reputable source like a government's health department.

Therefore, I urge you to reevaluate your efforts on this app.

Comment: Thanks picacode for telling about this but i am doing this as a college assignment. I have no plans to publish it on app store :)

Comment: Thank you again :)