# React Native Async Storage set item function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, async-await, asyncstorage

I am using async storage in my items listing app. The problem i am facing is that, my first item does not get stored in the async till i enter the second item. i am saving array of objects with the help of react hooks
E.g if I enter items as
1)Apples
2)Bananas
then only apples will get saved in the async while bananas will not be saved until i enter the third item.

```
const [getWant, setwant] = useState([]);

const saveData = async () => {
      AsyncStorage.clear()
       try {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem("@pantry102", JSON.stringify(getWant))
         console.log(getWant)
         alert('Data successfully saved')
       } catch (e) {
         alert('Failed to save the data to the storage')
       }
     }
const readData = async () => {
        try {
          const userData= await AsyncStorage.getItem("@pantry102")
          const userData2 = JSON.parse(userData)
          if (userData2 !== null) {
            console.log(userData2)
            setwant(userData2)
            
          }
        } catch (e) {
        alert('Failed to fetch the data from storage')
        }
      }
useEffect(() => {
      readData()
      }, [])
```

the saveData function gets called inside the additems fucntion which is envoked when textbox is submitted

Comment: based on what output do you say that the item doesn't get saved?

Comment: i used the console.log it shows empty array on first save and on second save it contains the first item. Also when i reload the app to check the old saved data only the first item gets displayed when both item should be. Here is my snack expo link https://snack.expo.io/@moeez71/7f7d44 you can test it yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to await to clear data. It is async in nature too.

`await AsyncStorage.clear()`

```
const saveData = async () => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.clear();
    await AsyncStorage.setItem("@pantry102", JSON.stringify(getWant));
    console.log(getWant);
    alert("Data successfully saved");
  } catch (e) {
    alert("Failed to save the data to the storage");
  }
};
```

I will suggest, just override it. No need to clear.

Read More: https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/api#clear

:-D

Comment: yeah i fixed it using await in my AddItem function with await setWant(). Thanks though :)

Answer (score 0):

There is an open source library [react-native-easy-app](https://github.com/chende008/react-native-easy-app/blob/master/README.en-US.md), which wraps the use of AsyncStorage, through which you can access any data in AsncStorage synchronously, maybe it can solve your problem, there is [sample](https://github.com/chende008/Sample_Hook) program below, maybe you can refer to it. [code](https://github.com/chende008/Sample_Hook/blob/master/src/Main/Home/view/StorageController.js).